# Fix these ugly results when implementing moving up view when keyboard pops up

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

Here is my code.

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)


@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification){
    guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else {return}
    guard let keyboardSize = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else {return}

    let keyboardFrame = keyboardSize.cgRectValue
    if (self.view.frame.origin.y == 0) {
        self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardFrame.height
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if (self.view.frame.origin.y != 0) {
        self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to just move up the textview instead of the entire viewcontroller?

Comment: You already have the methods that are called when the keyboard opens and closes, so just adjust the frame of the textview in those methods. Would that not work?

Comment: with smaller devices its not terrible. but with the XR Max, its just ugly. I can play with the values. I just wasnt sure if there was something better than what I had.

Comment: I’m not exactly sure about what is ugly about the screen with the keyboard. There isn’t much to change on that screen as it’s just a textfield, button and count label. If you move the textview it won’t be in the right position for the other elements. Moving the whole viewcontroller is common practice for opening the keyboard.

Comment: When I put the application logo, it scrolls off screen, so that only thing you see if the textField. I removed the logo from the first image just because. On Android, it moves it up just enough to be right above the keyboard, so *maybe* I can get the height of the keyboard and subtract it from the bottom contraint, and then set the height to be that.